# If a job is Seasonal Is there some sort of "unspoken expectancy" for how long you stay?

Tags: new-job

I was hired for a seasonal Spring position starting tomorrow which states in the terms that "any employee may leave with/without notice or reason at any time".
Is it considered impolite or is there anything wrong with leaving after two months?  I plan to leave in a formal and polite manner but feel kind of bad leaving before they cut down my hours.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is a spoken (written) expectancy for how long you stay.  While it is possible that an unspoken expectation exists that conflicts what is written, it is completely reasonable to accept what the company offers in their written communications.

You don't know, if you plan on leaving in two months, if it will before or after they start cutting down your hours.  And if you give 2 weeks notice, you'll certainly be considered professional and polite in your leaving process.

Answer (score 2):

Generally seasonal positions are intended to be short term with little or no training time required.  This means that if you can give them a few months they will be happy to take your time and reward you with your paycheck.  I would not say anything until you are ready to give notice.  It may get closer to that time and you may find you have a few weeks or month more availability than you expected.

Still give them 2 weeks notice even though it is not required.  You may decide later on that you would like to return later on and this will allow them time to plan their schedules accordingly.